# Django localflavor field overwrite breaks form

Tags: python, django, django-localflavor

I have the following form, which generates a Value error upon submition.

ValueError at /en/orders/create/

The view orders.views.order_create didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

my form:

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Order
from localflavor.us.forms import USZipCodeField


class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    postal_code = USZipCodeField()

    class Meta:
        model = Order

        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'address',
                  'postal_code', 'city']
```

my model:

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(_('e-mail'))
    address = models.CharField(_('address'), max_length=250)
    postal_code = models.CharField(_('postal code'), max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(_('city'), max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created', )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Order {self.id}'
```

my view:

```py
def order_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            order.save()

            request.session['order_id'] = order.id

            # redirect for payment return
            return redirect(reverse('payment:process'))

    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
        return render(request,
                      'orders/order/create.html',
                      {'cart': cart, 'form': form})
```

Traceback:

```py
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/orders/create/

Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rosetta',
 'parler',
 'localflavor',
 'shop.apps.ShopConfig',
 'cart.apps.CartConfig',
 'orders.apps.OrdersConfig',
 'payment.apps.PaymentConfig',
 'coupons.apps.CouponsConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/[user]/.virtualenvs/shop/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/[user]/.virtualenvs/shop/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    raise ValueError(

Exception Type: ValueError at /en/orders/create/
Exception Value: The view orders.views.order_create didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

The process works fine, and redirects to a payment form, without this line in the form : postal_code = USZipCodeField()

I cant seem to understand what causes the error.

Expected behavior:

On valid form, redirect to payment.

On invalid form, validation error that is raised by USZipCodeField: "Enter a zip code in the format XXXXX or XXXXX-XXXX."

Comment: Hi, I'm one of the maintainers of localflavor. You could have hit a bug. Which version of Django and localflavor are you using? Could you include the full stack trace in your question? If it is a bug, we should make a report in github. Thanks.

Comment: @BenKonrath, Django==3.0.6, django-localflavor==3.0.1. Please tell if you need any other details

Comment: Just seeing the stack trace would be useful. It saves me having copy and paste you code to see where to look further.

Comment: Added Traceback to OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that the code isn't rendering the form in the case that the form isn't valid. For an invalid form, the function returns `None` which is exactly the error message you're seeing. Maybe you're submitting an empty or invalid value? Try this modified (untested) version:

```
def order_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()

            request.session['order_id'] = order.id

            # redirect for payment return
            return redirect(reverse('payment:process'))

    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()

    # FIXME Where does 'cart' come from?
    return render(request,
                  'orders/order/create.html',
                  {'cart': cart, 'form': form})
```

Does this work?

You might want to consider using the built-in `CreateView` to avoid boilerplate form processing code:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/flattened-index/#CreateView

If you haven't used class-based views, it's definitely something to look into. I find I can move a little faster using them but they do take a bit of time to learn and make the flow a little harder to follow when things don't work. Here are the full docs for the class based views:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/